# Proof of a limit without geometry

Tags: calculus, limits

Can anbody write a proof that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}-e^x = 0$$ without using a geometrical representation of the function? Is this something that I should know for Calculus I? (I am teaching myself).

Thanks!

Comment: How would you prove this WITH geometry? :) :) Teaching yourself? Go for it! This e-power stuff comes around a lot in Calc2 (and of course beyond)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}-e^x = \lim_{x\to\infty}-e^{-x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-1}{e^x} = 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a great answer; very straightforward!

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to showing that $$\lim_{n\to-\infty} e^x = 0$$

What you must prove is that for every $\epsilon$, there exists some $M\in\mathbb R$ for which you can show that for every $x<m$, the value $$e^x<\epsilon.$$

This is the definition of a limit.